# Regex to avoid some characters and some character combinations

Tags: java, regex

I have to create a text box where user input comment and I have to validate that, this input does not contains below characters(character combination).

> :|, &,  ; , $ , % , @ , ' , " , \' , \" , <> , (), +, CR, LF, \
>
> The list above is comma delimited, so if two characters appear between
>   a set of commas, it’s the character combination that is potentially
>   malicious, not the character in isolation

I tried to create regex for this and tried Positive Lookahead also, but not working anything for me. I have gone through some earlier questions also, but not found solution for my query.

I am able to validate single malicious characters but not the combination.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: I have tried something like ".*[^&;$%@\'\"].*[C(?!R)].*"

Comment: Are not CR and LF mean to be control chars `\r` and `\n`?

Comment: ya that's fine I just did it for the sake of trying the combination of characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for characters, that's really simple. You can just specify what type of chars are not allowed in the string by using `[^]`, in your case, `[^&;$%@\'\"+\\]`

`[^&;$%@\'\"+\\]*` will match a string that doesn't contain the mentioned symbols.

As for the combinations, regex has **negative lookahead** for that. Before the engine starts matching something, it can test if there aren't patterns present in the string. Syntax: `(?!.*thing1|.*thing2|...)` (the `.*` is needed so that the whole string is checked, not only the next word, so `(?!.*:\||.*<>|.*\(\)|.*CR|.*LF)`

All together: `^(?!.*:\||.*<>|.*\(\)|.*CR|.*LF)[^&;$%@\'\"+\\]*$`

Comment: Thanks Andris, by just little modification I implemented it in JAVA. Thanks for it.