# Regex for: contains some of these characters ( #%&*:<>?/{|} )

Tags: java, regex

I want to check if a string contains these characters: `#%&*:<>?/{|}`

I'm thinking of using the `string.matches("regex")` method to do it in a single line, but it returns `false`. Please provide any regex code make it work fine.

My code is below, but it doesn't works as I want:

```
String fileName;

if (fileName.matches("[#%&*:<>?/{|}]")) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Watch my code in an edit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java function to return if string contains illegal characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635391/java-function-to-return-if-string-contains-illegal-characters)

Comment: Similar : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31267938/regex-to-avoid-some-characters-and-some-character-combinations have a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you do have is that `String#matches` checks the whole `String` and if it matches the given regex. The given regex combined with `String#matches` would check if the `filename` would match exactly one character and this character would be one of the characters given in the character group from your regex.

But as your input, the filename, should be more than one character long your getting the correct result, but it´s not what you want.

You could either create a `Matcher` and use it´s `find` method, or use wildcards for and after the character group.

`Matcher` solution

```
public static boolean findSpecialChar(String input) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[#%&*:<>?/{|}]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    // Check if the regex can be found anywhere
    return matcher.find();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(findSpecialChar("#fdhdfjdf"));
    System.out.println(findSpecialChar("fdhdfjdf"));
}
```

O/P :

```
true
false
```

Regex wildcard solution

```
public static boolean findSpecialChar(String input) {
    // Use .* to indicate there can be anything and this special chars
    String regex = ".*[#%&*:<>?/{|}].*";
    return input.matches(regex);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(findSpecialChar("#fdhdfjdf"));
    System.out.println(findSpecialChar("fdhdfjdf"));
}
```

O/P

```
true 
false
```

Comment: THANKS!! Good explanation

Answer (score 1):

```
String sequence = "qwe 123 :@~ ";    
String withoutSpecialChars = sequence.replaceAll("[^\\w\\s]", "");    
String spacesAsPluses = withoutSpecialChars.replaceAll("\\s", "+");    
System.out.println("without special chars: '"+withoutSpecialChars+ '\'');
System.out.println("spaces as pluses: '"+spacesAsPluses+'\'');
```

Comment: Regex dont works. Invalid escape sequence ( \s )

Comment: I suppose even if it were written in a proper programming language, the regex wouldn't solve OPs question....